# How to get new access token when old token is expired (Google sheet api V4)

Tags: vb.net, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to access to my google sheet database using vb.net google spreadsheet api v4. I worked well on the first time, but the access token gets expired in a few days after. Without logging in google account and say yes to some security about access permission, I can not access to the database anymore. I'm new to vb.net so I tried to use chatgpt's code to retrieve get new access token task, but unfortunately, it does not help much. The "response" variable is getting System.NullReferenceException error and I dont know how to fix it. Here is my code, so please tell me where I was wrong and how to fix it.
Any answer would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
'Range in my google sheet table, named "Users"
Dim rng As String = "Users!A1:D2"
    ' Define the scope of access needed for the Google Sheets API
    Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    scopes.Add(Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets)

    ' Load the client credentials from the client.json file
    Dim credentialsFile As String = myClientjson
    Dim credentialsStream As Stream = New FileStream(credentialsFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim clientSecrets As GoogleClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(credentialsStream)

    Dim datastore As IDataStore = New FileDataStore(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "MyCredentials"))
    ' Create the authorization code flow with the specified scopes
    Dim flow As New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer() With {
    .DataStore = datastore,
    .ClientSecrets = clientSecrets.Secrets,
    .Scopes = scopes
})
    ' Get the user credential
    Dim credential As UserCredential = New UserCredential(flow, "user", Nothing)

    service = New SheetsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
                              .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                              .ApplicationName = "testApp"
                })
    request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, rng)


    Dim response As ValueRange = request.Execute()
```

Comment: are you sure its not the refresh token expiring

Comment: When I used this code <Using stream As New FileStream(myclientjson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                                                             {SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets},
                                                             "user",
                                                             CancellationToken.None).Result                     End Using>

Comment: I got error "token expired or revoked", but when I changed to the code above, there was only the "response" variable got error. I still think it is because of token expired, but I dont know where and how to fix it.

Comment: change "user" to some other text string and it will ask you to authorize again

Comment: but I dont want to authorize again on everytime token expires. I want to renew it so my users dont need manual authorization from me again

Comment: while your application is in testing refresh tokens expire after seven Days once its in production they will stop expiring.   you don't need long lived token's while you are in development